# How to make this C++ code more DRY?

Tags: c++, dry, code-cleanup

I have these two methods on a class that differ only in one method call. Obviously, this is very un-DRY, especially as both use the same formula.

```
int PlayerCharacter::getAttack() {
    int attack;
    attack = 1 + this->level;
    for(int i = 0; i < this->current_equipment; i++) {
        attack += this->equipment[i].getAttack();
    }
    attack *= sqrt(this->level);
    return attack;
}
int PlayerCharacter::getDefense() {
    int defense;
    defense = 1 + this->level;
    for(int i = 0; i < this->current_equipment; i++) {
        defense += this->equipment[i].getDefense();
    }
    defense *= sqrt(this->level);
    return defense;
}
```

How can I tidy this up in C++?

Comment: `this.`? Post us some real code. :)

Comment: What GMan said. Also, are `attack` and `defense` global variables or did you omit their definition?

Comment: *facepalm* - Well, this is my first real C++ after months of other languages :P. Could be worse, I could of done `self.` since most of it was Python.

Comment: @sbi: While the other problem was idiocy, that one was a copy/paste error.

Comment: looks like you have an off-by-one error in your loops too

Comment: It didn't help that I had to work to discover what DRY meant. The the number of people that could provide an answer is larger than the number that will understand the question.  You may have limited the responses.

Comment: @Clifford: I decided I was too lazy to google this. What did you come up with?

Comment: @sbi: Don't Repeat Yourself is my best guess

Comment: @Dennis: Ah, yeah, redundancy. That would make sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, what you have is fine, as it will allow you to tweak attack/defense more than if you represented both of them with one function.  Once you start testing your game, you'll begin balancing attack/defense formulas, so having separate functions for them is fine.

The whole concept of DRY [don't repeat yourself] is [hopefully] to prevent your code from becoming a huge copy & paste fest.  In your situation, the defense/attack formulas will change over time [for example, what if characters have buffs/status-ailment? A specific status ailment might cut defense in half, while increasing attack by 2 (Berserk, FF reference, heh)]

Comment: I agree.  While there are (theoretically) ways to DRY-ify the underlying mathematics of what you're doing (using some function pointers), you're likely to wind up writing different wrapper methods for each in the long haul anyway, as (like @ItzWarty suggests) you begin to tamper with the two values in different ways.

Answer (score 18):

One easy way is to represent all of a piece of equipment's attributes in an array, indexed by an enum.

```
enum Attributes {
  Attack, 
  Defense,
  AttributeMAX
};

class Equipment {
  std::vector<int> attributes;

  Equipment(int attack, int defense): attributes(AttributeMAX)
  {
    attributes[ATTACK] = attack;
    attributes[DEFENSE] = defense;
  }

};
```

Then you change your function to

```
int PlayerCharacter::getAttribute(int& value, Attribute attribute) {
    value = 1 + this->level;
    for(int i = 0; i <= current_equipment; i++) {
        value += this->equipment[i].attributes[attribute];
    }
    value *= sqrt(this->level);
    return value;
}
```

And you can call it like so

```
  player.getAttribute(player.attack, Attack);
```

Comment: Thought of this one too, but was too lazy to spell it out. =)

Comment: This is a good solution since it doesn't obfuscate the intent of the code.  However, it does tend to obfuscate the usage.  But that is EASILY fixed by creating two wrapper routines called getAttack and getDefence that in turn calls with routine.  (EDIT) But I will say that player.getAttribute(player.attack, Attack) is really clear in it's own right.

Comment: +1. You'll need to initialize `attributes` to the number of Attributes before you assign to it in the ctor, of course.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought vector dynamically expanded if you try to index it out of range.

Answer (score 6):

From a strict refactoring point of view, you could do this:

```
int PlayerCharacter::getDefense() {
    return getAttribute(&EquipmentClass::getDefense);
}

int PlayerCharacter::getOffense() {
    return getAttribute(&EquipmentClass::getOffense);
}

int PlayerCharacter::getAttribute(int (EquipmentClass::*attributeFun)()) {
    int attribute = 0;
    attribute= 1 + this->level;
    for(int i = 0; i <= current_equipment; i++) {
        attribute += this->equipment[i].*attributeFun();
    }
    attribute *= sqrt(this->level);
    return attribute;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

well, I would at least consider extracting `sqrt(this.level);` as a separate function called `getLevelModifier()`

and

```
defense = 1 + this.level;

attack = 1 + this.level;
```

could be

```
defense = getBaseDefense();

attack= getBaseAttack();
```

Not only does this add flexibility, it also auto-documents your function.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on other code in the application it may or may not be worth it but an OOP approach would make defense and attack values objects of a class rather than a plain `int`. Then you could derive them from a common base class that has a get() method that calls a virtual getEquipmentRate() method defined by each of the subclasses as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

IMO, ItzWarty makes a reasonable point -- you may want to just leave the code alone. Assuming you decide that changing it is a good thing though, you could do something like this:

```
class equipment { 
public:
    int getAttack();
    int getDefense();
};

int PlayerCharacter::getBattleFactor(int (equipment::*get)()) { 
    int factor = level + 1;
    for (int i=0; i<current_equipment; ++i)
        factor += equipment[i].*get();
    return factor * sqrt(level + 1);
}
```

You'd call this like:

```
int attack = my_player.getBattleFactor(&equipment::getAttack);
```

or:

```
int defense = my_player.GetBattleFactor(&equipment::getDefense);
```

Edit:

Another obvious possibility would be to decree that any one piece of equipment can *only* be defensive or offensive. In this case, things become simpler still, to the point that it might even be questionable whether you really need a function at all:

```
class PlayerCharacter {
    std::vector<equipment> d_equip;
    std::vector<equipment> o_equip;

// ...

int d=level+1+std::accumulate(d_equip.begin(), d_equip.end(), 0)*sqrt(level+1);

int o=level+1+std::accumulate(o_equip.begin(), o_equip.end(), 0)*sqrt(level+1);
```

Comment: +1 for `BattleFactor`. It sounds awesome and makes we want to play it (whatever it is).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from [ltzWarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669915/how-to-make-this-c-code-more-dry/2669923#2669923)'s answer I would recommend refactoring your loop into a function for better readability:

```
int PlayerCharacter::getEquipmentAttack() {
    int attack = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= current_equipment; i++) {
        attack += this.equipment[i].getAttack();
    }
    return attack;
}
int PlayerCharacter::getAttack() {
    int attack = 1 + this->level;
    attack += getEquipmentAttack();
    attack *= sqrt(this->level);
    return attack;
}
```

Also, when you declare your local variable `attack` you should [initialize it immediately](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/coding-standards.html#faq-27.7).